# Is it possible to listen to a database unavailable/available event in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, hikaricp

I have searched for a while but haven't found any hint on how to be able to react if the database connection goes down while a Spring Boot application is running.
We had that problem today in production. First time in 5 years running that application.
The database was unavailable for 3 minutes. Lot's of stack traces. Requests have failed.

I thought of wouldn't it be nice to listen to an event from Hikari, that the database is unavailable. Store this information somewhere. Using a request filter that returns something properly like an error code and listen to another event from Hikari, that the database is available again...

Haven't found something in that direction.

Any hints please?

Comment: Not exactly what you're asking for, but there is [Spring Boot Actuator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html) which (among other things) provides a database health check. You could configure a load balancer to drop traffic with an error code if your application is unhealthy.

Comment: Also thought about it and will test that approach.